# Displaying Iframe on top of image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Problem

I want to display an iframe within an image, but have no idea how to do this. Is there a better way than purely positioning with css?

I have a html page that displays other websites, and I would like to display an iframe within the screen of the image below on that page.

[image]

Comment: In the outermost div add position:relative in css and put image and then iframe. For div.iframe the css will be position:absolute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made the screen a background image and then used a absolute positioned iframe.
i added a YouTube iframe to the screen in the demo.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/ecwydkec/6/)

```
.outer {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hnLq.png');
    width:420px;
    height:365px;
}
.inner {
    position: relative;
    background-color:;
    left: 67px;
    top: 109px;
    width:277px;
    height:150px;
}
```

............

```
<div class="outer"><iframe class="inner"></iframe>
```

you could even use a 2 or 3px border-radius to match the image.

Comment: Thank you, would recommend using relative positioning for the .inner class however.

Comment: yeah relative would be better

Comment: @Dan Cundy Changed to relative positioning.

Comment: First ticked answer ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want to place the iframe in a container that is positioned absolutely. Then place it directly over the image. Here is an example. Please note the iframe link will not work inside of the fiddle due to JS Same origin issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/weyg1opk/

```
<div class="image_container">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hnLq.png" class="preview_image">
<div class="container">
    <iframe class="iframe_example" name="iframe_example">You do not have iframes enabled</iframe>   
</div>
```

```
.container {
    position: relative;  
    top: 110px;
    left: 68px
}
.image_container {
    width: 421px;
    height: 365px;
}
.preview_image{
    position: absolute;
}
.iframe_example {
    width: 270px;
    height: 155px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: you should make the screen a background image.

Comment: This was just a quick example. You're right, a background image would be better. This illustrates the point, however.

Comment: You should do it the right way because people with limited CSS skill will use the code as is, not knowing its the wrong way.

Comment: Who is to say it is the wrong way? Background images are often misused and overused. It does not *have* to be a background image here. Please stop trolling SO.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can:

- Crop the image into pieces and replace the screen image with a iframe without border and fixed size

or

- Use the monitor as background, and use a div with absolute position to exact match the screen size and position.